# SQL Query Conditions on Sums

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I have a question regarding the display of data and how to get the query to display the way I want.  Our BI people are busy on other projects so we (finance) are left to pick up the slack. I am going to dump this in a ODBC to EXCEL, if that is relevant.

My Query is selecting the correct information but I want two columns for the `SUM (INVOICE.INVAMT)`, I want a column that is the sum of `INVOICE.INVAMT` (or NULL) when `INVOICE.INVDATE` is less than `FUNDEPTPER.STARTDATE` and a column for the sum of `INVOICE.INVAMT` when `INVOICE.INVDATE` is between and including `FUNDEPTPER.STARTDATE` and `FUNDDEPTPER.STOPDATE`, (OR NULL). A grand total would be nice too.

I can do one at a time, but not both - my gut says this can be done - but I cannot figure out how.

Your help is greatly appreciated.  I do not need to know specifically (ie. the exact query language), if you could even explain high level I might be able to get it (if it is possible???)

My Query if you need it:

```
SELECT FUNDERS.CODE, BILLBATCH.BATCH_ID, BILLBATCH.BATCHNO,  SUM (INVOICE.INVAMT) AS [TOTAL CURRENT] 
FROM FUNDERS INNER JOIN ORDERS ON FUNDERS.FUNDER_ID= ORDERS.FUNDER_ID    
INNER JOIN INVOICE ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID=INVOICE.ORDER_ID    
INNER JOIN FUNDEPTPER ON FUNDEPTPER.PERIOD_ID = INVOICE.PERIOD_ID    
INNER JOIN BILLBATCH ON BILLBATCH.BATCH_ID= FUNDEPTPER.BATCH_ID    
WHERE BILLBATCH.BATCHNO = '?' AND INVOICE.INVTYPE='Invoice' 
      AND INVOICE.INVDATE BETWEEN FUNDEPTPER.STARTDATE AND FUNDEPTPER.STOPDATE    
GROUP BY FUNDERS.CODE, BILLBATCH.BATCH_ID, BILLBATCH.BATCHNO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with conditional aggregation

```
SELECT f.CODE, bb.BATCH_ID, bb.BATCHNO,
      SUM(i.INVAMT) AS TotalTotal,
      SUM(case when i.INVDATE BETWEEN fp.STARTDATE AND fp.STOPDATE then i.invamt else 0
          end) as TotalCurrent
      SUM(case when i.INVDATE < fp.STARTDATE Athen i.invamt else 0
          end) as TotalBefore
FROM FUNDERS f INNER JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON f.FUNDER_ID = o.FUNDER_ID  INNER JOIN
     INVOICE i
     ON o.ORDER_ID = i.ORDER_ID INNER JOIN
     FUNDEPTPER fp
     ON fp.PERIOD_ID = i.PERIOD_ID INNER JOIN
     BILLBATCH bb
     ON bb.BATCH_ID= fp.BATCH_ID    
WHERE bb.BATCHNO = '?' AND i.INVTYPE = 'Invoice' 
GROUP BY f.CODE, bb.BATCH_ID, bb.BATCHNO;
```

This query also introduces table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: I never thought of a `CASE statement` can be found within a `SUM()`

Comment: Combining the `case` statement with aggregations -- "conditional aggregation" -- is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I need to break down your needs to understand your inquiry.

You're requirement  - two columns for the SUM (INVOICE.INVAMT):

1. sum of INVOICE.INVAMT (or NULL) when INVOICE.INVDATE is less than FUNDEPTPER.STARTDATE

   `SELECT sum(invoice.invamt) 
   FROM funders 
    INNER JOIN ORDERS 
     ON FUNDERS.FUNDER_ID= ORDERS.FUNDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN INVOICE 
     ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID=INVOICE.ORDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN FUNDEPTPER 
     ON FUNDEPTPER.PERIOD_ID = INVOICE.PERIOD_ID
   WHERE INVOICE.INVDATE < FUNDEPTPER.STARTDATE;`
2. sum of INVOICE.INVAMT when INVOICE.INVDATE is 
    between and including FUNDEPTPER.STARTDATE and FUNDDEPTPER.STOPDATE

   `SELECT sum(invoice.invamt) 
   FROM funders 
    INNER JOIN ORDERS 
     ON FUNDERS.FUNDER_ID= ORDERS.FUNDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN INVOICE 
     ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID=INVOICE.ORDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN FUNDEPTPER 
     ON FUNDEPTPER.PERIOD_ID = INVOICE.PERIOD_ID
   WHERE INVOICE.INVDATE between FUNDERTPER.STARTDATE and FUNDDERTPER.STOPDATE`